# How to Post data on web server using AFNetWorking in iPhone

Tags: iphone, web-services, afnetworking

I am making use of AFNetworking library for the first time and i have successfully implemented json parsing and it is working perfectly, now i need to make one registration page in which user will fill all the details like username, password,question,answer,name and it will post all the data on web server. I have tried with several example,however it is not posting on web server.

Below is the code for posting on web server

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apollowebservice.10summer.com/registration.php"];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];

NSMutableDictionary *requestArray = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[requestArray setObject: @"Kashif"
                 forKey: @"user_name"];
[requestArray setObject: @"Kashif.jilani@triffort.com"
                 forKey: @"user_email"];
[requestArray setObject:@"ila@1234" forKey:@"user_password"];
[requestArray setObject:@"What is your name" forKey:@"user_question"];
[requestArray setObject:@"Kashif Answer" forKey:@"user_answer"];

[httpClient postPath:@"method" parameters:requestArray success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // reponseObject will hold the data returned by the server.

}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error retrieving data: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Provide an example on how you are trying and failing this.

Comment: Whats written in the error?

Comment: Error retrieving data: Error Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 404" UserInfo=0x8929000 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://apollowebservice.10summer.com/method, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 404}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can go with a blank baseURL and have the path be

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];

// ...your code....

[httpClient postPath:@"http://apollowebservice.10summer.com/registration.php" parameters:requestArray success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // reponseObject will hold the data returned by the server.
}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error retrieving data: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: It work like a charm thanks very much i also added one more parameter httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/json"]; I just need to know that why it was not work previously we only passed the url path in different way

Comment: If you are going to make JSON requests, consider using `AFJSONRequestOperation` instead of HTTP operation.