# Iphone - AFNetworking Login Form always returns 404

Tags: iphone, forms, authentication, afnetworking

I'm having troubles with AFNetworking, decided to use it since ASIHTTP is long deprecated, and I'm trying to use it in a login form request, but the response code is always -1011.

here is my code :

```
NSString *urltest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/", SERVER_ADDRESS, API_ADDRESS];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urltest];
NSLog(@"url address : %@",url);
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
httpClient.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = TRUE;
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        _email.text, @"email",
                        _password.text, @"password",
                        nil];
```

// Here I try doing my login request using AFHTTPRequestOperation

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/auth/login" parameters:params];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//Notice the different method here!
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [httpClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
                                                                        }
                                                                        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
                                                                            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                                                        }];
//Enqueue it instead of just starting it.
[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

// Here I try doing my login request using the postPath:parameters: method

```
[httpClient postPath:@"/auth/login" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"AuthOK" sender:self];
    NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Request Successful, response '%@'", responseStr);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Request failed with code %d for %@ for request : %@",error.code , error.localizedDescription,httpClient.baseURL);    
}];
```

And none of these two methods are working, I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong somewhere

btw, the server I login to, has an unsigned ssl certificate, but I handled the error by adding

```
#define _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_ 1
```

in AFURLConnectionOperation.h

I use Charles to monitor http requests, and it gives me a "SSLHandshake: Remote host closed connection during handshake"

My app runs with iOS 5.

Anyone has insights on this?

Leo

Comment: The Charles error means you don't have HTTPS proxying set up correctly.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `[AFHTTPClient postPath:parameters:success:failure:]`.  In the debugger type `po request` and look at the URL it's using.  Is it correct?

Comment: Hi aaron, thanks for answering, I use the same address I used back when using ASIHTTPRequest, and I know the url is fine. I guessed that the HTTPS proxy is no set up properly, but I cannot figure out why, the server I'm working on ,as I said before, has an unsigned certificate. As for the breakpoint it gives me `error: use of undeclared identifier 'request'
error: 1 errors parsing expression` . the url described is the correct one, without the postPath extension (/auth/login)

Comment: That means you set the breakpoint before `request` is defined.

Comment: I understood that, but there is no request variable in the part where I put the breakpoint..

Comment: Then you put the breakpoint in the wrong place.

Comment: no I think the debugger doesn't recognize 'request' that's it. I still haven't gotten any closer to the answer, after looking through many pages of stackoverflow..thanks a lot for taking some time helping me aaron, I appreciate it. I'm not really good with debugging, never really used the breakpoints..could you give me a bit more help?

Comment: found my answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702486/how-to-post-data-on-web-server-using-afnetworking-in-iphone?rq=1). Initialized my httpClient with @"" for the url, and then in post path, I put the whole url for login, and it worked. thanks for your time aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well my solution was to initialize my request with an empty url and then in the postPath, put the whole address.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Charles' SSL Certificate on your device to decrypt SSL traffic

http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-connections-from-within-iphone-applications/